# SIMD SSE2 instructions in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, simd, sse2

I'm currently rewriting a program that used 64 bit words to use 128 bit words. I am trying to use SIMD SSE2 intrinsics from Intel. My new program, that uses the SIMD intrinsics, is about 60% percent slower than the original when I had expected to to be around twice as fast.  When I looked at the assembly code for each of them, they were very similar and about the same length. However, the object code (compiled file) was 60% longer.

I also ran callgrind on the two programs, which told me how many instruction reads there were per line. I found that the SIMD version of my program often had fewer instructions reads for the same action than in the original version. Ideally, that should happen, but it doesn't make sense because the SIMD version takes longer to run.

My question:
Do the SSE2 intrinsics convert into more assembly instructions? Do the SSE2 instructions take longer to run? Or is there some other reason that my new program is so slow?

Additional notes: I am programming in C, on Linux Mint, and compiling with gcc -O3 -march=native.

Comment: You should post some code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Before you ever touch SSE, read this http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html. Otherwise you are going to do more harm than good.

Comment: You ran cachegrind, and only looked at the instruction reads?

Comment: What else should I look at with cachegrind?

Comment: Is there a particular section of the manual that I should read?

Comment: chapters 4 and 5 you should focus on

Comment: I actually made a typo in my post. I used callgrind and I'm viewing it with kcachegrind

Comment: Post your code - there are a lot of common rookie mistakes that SIMD noobs make that are easy to spot if we can see the code.